# Where can I see a history of flags?

Tags: discussion

I got a warning that my flag had been rejected.  I wanted to ask a question on meta about that, as after I had raised the flag that the "Answer" was not an answer, it was edited - which made it an answer, and the flag was rejected.

I tried to find the post on which I had raised the flag to provide a link, but I cannot find the section where my flag history is located.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can see your flag history by going to [your profile](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/16418/thronk) page, the Activity tab, then on the left side you'll see this:

> [image]

In that box, you'll notice the # helpful flags - that is a link which will take you to your flag history page. On that page you'll see the result of your flags.